# How to artificially load CPUs to a certain percentage point?

Tags: windows, winapi, cpu, cpu-usage

For the purpose of testing my app (that detects the current CPU usage) I need to set an artificial work load on the CPUs, for example: 10%, 20%, 30%, etc. up to a 100%. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Cpukiller 3: http://4sysops.com/archives/cpukiller-3-generate-cpu-load-artificially-to-slow-down-windows/ and there's this: http://www.jam-software.com/heavyload/

Comment: If you want to work for 10% of the time, just do exactly that. If you understand what 10% CPU utlization means, surely the solution is obvious. Which makes me think that the real question should be to ask what CPU utlization actually means.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Good point. Do you want to share?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time

Answer (score 4):

Use any cpu-bound code you want, then wax-on, wax-off.

In other words,

to achieve 50% load, run the cpu-bound code for x ms, then do nothing for x ms.

to achieve other loads, well, you do the math.

doing nothing is easy, sleep, pause, delay, etc.
   if c++ 11, try threads and

```
   std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
```